# Issue with insert (access/vb)

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've been already trying to solve this problem for two days, and i'm going no further with it.

I have two tables in my access application: one of them is called `tabDerroga`, where some documents' data are saved (mainly its protocol number, or "Protocolo"). Another one is called `tabLog`, and it's used to store logs. I also have a query that checks if there are any log related to a `Derroga`. If it does, there's no need to work with it anymore. But if it doesn't, I need to process it and then I save the log entry  detailing what I did. The `tabLog` table has a [Protocolo Derroga] foreign key/field that points to `tabDerroga`.[Protocolo]. No issue with it at all.

While creating the tables and the query, I've extensively tested everything *manually*, and it works flawlessly. If i create *any* entry in `tabLog` where the "foreign field" refers to a `tabDerroga` entry, this entry will be omitted on the query.

My problem starts when I add a row to `tabLog` through VBA. If I check the table manually after it, I can confirm that it had been added with success. **But the query won't see it**.

I can run the code hundreds of times, creating hundreds of rows with the same data, but somehow it seems to be "different" or "invisible" to the rest of the database. If I *copy* any of these rows and paste on a  new entry, this manually added will be instantly "visible" to the query, but all the other rows won't. And they all have the **SAME DATA**.

This is one of the ways I tried to accomplish the task:

```
MyRS.MoveFirst

MyRS.AddNew
    MyRS![Descrição] = "10 dias antes de vencer"
    MyRS![Protocolo derroga] = Protocolo
MyRS.Update

MyRS.Close
```

This gives me the **exactly same results**:

```
DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tabLog ([Protocolo derroga],[Descrição]) VALUES ('" & Protocolo & "','10 dias antes de vencer')"
```

So does this:

```
CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO tabLog ([Protocolo derroga],[Descrição]) VALUES ('" & Protocolo & "','10 dias antes de vencer')"
```

By the way, I've already checked if the problem is related with any sql injection issue by assembling the whole string first. Got the same results.

What am I missing? Do I need to "update" anything before the data is ready to be worked with? If so, why does it appear normally in the table?

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: too long didn't read...

Comment: Did you close and reopen the table where you are looking at the results?

Comment: Yes. Even closing the whole application and reopening it won't make the added rows "visible" to the query. I can see them on the table, i can edit them, i can delete them. But no query will "read" these entries.

Comment: What is the query like? You've said that your query will ignore entries if a corresponding entry in `tablog` has been found.

Comment: When is the query being executed?

Comment: The query:
`SELECT tabDerrogas.Protocolo, tabDerrogas.EQF, tabDerrogas.Validade, tabDerrogas.[Finalizada?]
FROM tabDerrogas LEFT JOIN tabLog ON tabDerrogas.Protocolo=tabLog.[Protocolo Derroga]
WHERE (Not (tabLog.Descrição="10 dias antes de vencer")) Or (tabLog.[Protocolo Derroga] Is Null);`

Comment: It gives me only the tabDerrogas entries where there aren't any entries in tabLog with this protocol at all OR if the entry's [Descrição] is different from "10 dias antes de vencer". No VBA-added entry on tabLog is recognized by the query.

Comment: The query is the first thing run. Once i use it to get the protocols, i can do whatever i need (send emails in this case), and then i save the log entry saying so. When i run it all over again, Derrogas with these freshly added logs should be ignored, but the query still lists them, because it wouldn't recognize the log.

Comment: Are the datatypes of the fields tabDerrogas.Protocolo and tabLog.[Protocolo Derroga] the same? If so, what are they?

Comment: Maybe you made it simple for us, but your query is excluding the record (via the WHERE clause) that you are adding in your question.  I assume you know that?

Comment: @JohnnyBones that's exactly what i want. The query is meant to list for me only entries that has not been done anything with, e.g. no log referring to this entry has been generated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How dumb I am. I've completely forgotten about the first and only universal rule on dealing with computers: If it doesn't work, reboot everything.

Went back home yesterday, and today everything is working as expected. No code change.

Thanks @TimLentine, @ JohnnyBones, @MurDeR and @MP24!